# How to extract the MAC id?

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to extract the MAC id from a set of related commands.

From the first command, the value (2,4) within the parenthesis `eth-1(2-04)` is applied in the second command to extract the MAC id from output of the second command.

How can I extract the MAC id which is in the same line as 2 4 in the output of the second command?

```
s1 = '''100 int-maint      debug(2-02) eth-10(2-00) maint(4-03)
101 bear-test      eth-1(2-04) eth-2(2-07)
102 int-test      eth-4(2-06) eth-7(2-05) eth-8(2-03) eth-9(2-01) gig-3(2-08) eth-3(4-02) eth-5(4-00) eth-6(4-01) gig-1(4-08) gig-2(4-10) poe-1(4-04) poe-2(4-05) poe-3(4-06) poe-4(4-07)
'''
# output of second command

r2 = '''
     2     4   101  00:80:a3:bf:72:d4      5
     2    10   101  00:e0:4b:52:56:56      7
     2    10   100  02:00:00:64:00:00      7
     2    10   102  02:00:00:66:00:00      6
     2     0   100  94:10:3e:b9:4f:5c      2
Switch  Port   FID      MAC-Address    Aging
     4     3   100  56:1a:5e:a2:4a:73      7
'''


import re
s1o = (next((x for x in s1.split() if 'eth-1(2-04)' in x), None))
print(s1o)
print(r2.split())
```

I have the output (shown below) so far. I am not sure if split() would be best way to break it down to extract this value 00:80:a3:bf:72:d4

```
eth-1(2-04)
['2', '4', '101', '00:80:a3:bf:72:d4', '5', '2', '10', '101', '00:e0:4b:52:56:56', '7', '2', '10', '100', '02:00:00:64:00:00', '7', '2', '10', '102', '02:00:00:66:00:00', '6', '2', '0', '100', '94:10:3e:b9:4f:5c', '2', 'Switch', 'Port', 'FID', 'MAC-Address', 'Aging', '4', '3', '100', '56:1a:5e:a2:4a:73', '7']
```

Expected Results: 00:80:a3:bf:72:d4

Comment: I am able to `grep '2     4'`  (with a tab in between) to acquire the row.

Comment: `print([x.split()[3] for x in r2.split('\n') if re.compile('^\s*2\s*4').findall(x)])` is it what you want?

Comment: How about `re.findall('..:..:..:..:..:..', r2)`?

Comment: Bear Brown, your code worked perfectly. Is there way to pass the `2` and `4` as a variables in [re.compile('^\s*2\s*4')] ? I would have to grab those values from the first command.

Comment: you can use format or  f-string if python3.6+, for example `print([x.split()[3] for x in r2.split('\n') if re.compile('^\s*{}\s*{}'.format(2,4)).findall(x)])`

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.x I forgot to mention.

Comment: my example should work

Comment: Yes, it did work. The format part would have to be changed to something like format(var1,var2).

Answer (score 1):

I am also a python beginner, I think this code help you

```
101 bear-test      eth-1(2-04) eth-2(2-07)
102 int-test      eth-4(2-06) eth-7(2-05) eth-8(2-03) eth-9(2-01) gig-3(2-08) eth-3(4-02) eth-5(4-00) eth-6(4-01) gig-1(4-08) gig-2(4-10) poe-1(4-04) poe-2(4-05) poe-3(4-06) poe-4(4-07)
'''
# output of second command

r2 = '''
     2     4   101  00:80:a3:bf:72:d4      5
     2    10   101  00:e0:4b:52:56:56      7
     2    10   100  02:00:00:64:00:00      7
     2    10   102  02:00:00:66:00:00      6
     2     0   100  94:10:3e:b9:4f:5c      2
Switch  Port   FID      MAC-Address    Aging
     4     3   100  56:1a:5e:a2:4a:73      7
'''


import re
s1o = (next((x for x in s1.split() if 'eth-1(2-04)' in x), None))
print(s1o)
base_list=(r2.split())
base_str=",".join(base_list)
pattren=r"(\w{2}):(\w{2}):(\w{2}):(\w{2}):(\w{2}):(\w{2})"
all_mac=re.findall(pattren,base_str)
print(all_mac)
print('###########################################')
for i in all_mac:
    result=re.sub(",",":",str(i))
    print(result)
```

Comment: Code is partly helpful. Not exactly what I was seeking to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To first command you can apply this pattern `eth-1\((\d)-0(\d)`

`eth-1\(` = match `eth-1(` literally

`(\d)` - match digit and store it inside first captruing group

`-0` - match `-0` literally,

`(\d)` - match digit and store it inside second captruing group

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vcvfMx/1)

Now, you can create another regular expression to apply to second command: `2\s+4\s+\d+\s+([^\s]+)`

`2` - match 2 literally, **this comes from first capturing group from first regex**

`\s+` - match one ore more whitespaces

`4` - match 4 literally, **this comes from second capturing group from first regex**

`\s+` - match one ore more whitespaces

`\d+` - match one ore more digits

`\s+` - match one ore more whitespaces

`([^\s]+)` - match one or more characterrs other than whitespace and store it inside capturing group, **this will capture your mac address**

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vcvfMx/2)

Comment: Nice example of application of regex.